# Bootstrap: collpase the entire tbody when clicking the header

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I have a table like this

[image: the table to collapse]

I want to achieve the goal that when "click here to Collapse" is clicked, the 3 rows behind will be collapsed and only the thead is rendered. Then, click it again, the full table will be shown again.

I tried the code like this, but it doesn't work at all. how to solve it? THanks!

```
<main class="container" role="main">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="bg-primary text-center font-weight-bold text-white" scope="col" colspan="7">
                     <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">click here to Collapse</a>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tdOdd">Mark</td>
                    <td class="tdEven">Otto</td>
                    <td class="tdOdd">@mdo</td>
                    <td class="tdEven">Otto</td>
                    <td class="tdOdd">@mdo</td>
                    <td class="tdEven">Otto</td>
                    <td class="tdOdd">@mdo</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tdOdd">Mark</td>
                    <td class="tdEven">Otto</td>
                    <td class="tdOdd">@mdo</td>
                    <td class="tdEven">Otto</td>
                    <td class="tdOdd">@mdo</td>
                    <td class="tdEven">Otto</td>
                    <td class="tdOdd">@mdo</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tdOdd">Mark</td>
                    <td class="tdEven">Otto</td>
                    <td class="tdOdd">@mdo</td>
                    <td class="tdEven">Otto</td>
                    <td class="tdOdd">@mdo</td>
                    <td class="tdEven">Otto</td>
                    <td class="tdOdd">@mdo</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </div>
    </table>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It somehow works if I change the code to below. But the animation effect looks awkward
in general, I removed the div and put the collapse directly to tbody.

```
<main class="container" role="main">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="bg-primary text-center font-weight-bold text-white" scope="col" colspan="7">
                     <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">click here to Collapse</a>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
            <tr>
                <td class="tdOdd">Mark</td>
                <td class="tdEven">Otto</td>
                <td class="tdOdd">@mdo</td>
                <td class="tdEven">Otto</td>
                <td class="tdOdd">@mdo</td>
                <td class="tdEven">Otto</td>
                <td class="tdOdd">@mdo</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tdOdd">Mark</td>
                <td class="tdEven">Otto</td>
                <td class="tdOdd">@mdo</td>
                <td class="tdEven">Otto</td>
                <td class="tdOdd">@mdo</td>
                <td class="tdEven">Otto</td>
                <td class="tdOdd">@mdo</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tdOdd">Mark</td>
                <td class="tdEven">Otto</td>
                <td class="tdOdd">@mdo</td>
                <td class="tdEven">Otto</td>
                <td class="tdOdd">@mdo</td>
                <td class="tdEven">Otto</td>
                <td class="tdOdd">@mdo</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</main>
```

Comment: For future travelers, this appears to be a known issue and how `tbody`s (unfortunately) work. See: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/7929